# Where to find the Click event in treeview nodes?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, treeview

I'm having a problem with the treeview 
I cant find a way to find the click event in each child nodes

Here's a sample image
[image]

here's what Ive tried so far.

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Level = 0 Then
        MsgBox("1")
    ElseIf TreeView1.SelectedNode.Level = 1 Then
        MsgBox("2")
    ElseIf TreeView1.SelectedNode.Level = 2 Then
        MsgBox("3")
    ElseIf TreeView1.SelectedNode.Level = 3 Then
        MsgBox("4")
    ElseIf TreeView1.SelectedNode.Level = 4 Then
        MsgBox("5")
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is in every child node the message box always says it's 2

Comment: So you are saying the level is always 1 ? I had made my own functions while working with TreeViews ... You could make a function that returns the level of the child you just clicked, but its weird that this "basic" function doesnt seem to work in your case

Comment: Which is perfectly normal because the Level property gets the depth of the current Node in the TreeView. If you select one of the two parent nodes, the MessageBox will show '1'. So please explain further what you want to achieve and what is not working at this time.

Comment: `if(selectedNode.Parent != null)` its child node

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys..What I want is to get click event of every child nodes..do you have any idea?

Comment: In the image as you can see above how can I know that the child node "Search" is Clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event you're using is the good event. If you want to get the new selected node, simply use the `EventArgs` object in your event handler (parameter named `e`). Following code is C# not VB.Net, but it's really simple:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    // Use the e parameter to get the new selected node
    MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text);
}
```